# Asymptotic estimate for Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma

Tags: analysis, asymptotics

Let $f$ be a real-valued, $L^1$ integrable function on the interval $[a,b]$.  Then the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma tells us that: $$\int_a^bf(x)\sin(2\pi nx)dx\rightarrow0  \text{  as  } n\rightarrow\infty.$$

Does this have any asymptotic estimate attached to it?  i.e. for sufficiently nice $f$ (say continuously differentiable), do we have the estimate that, say:
$$\int_a^bf(x)\sin(2\pi nx)dx= O(1/n)$$
or something similar?

Any kind of reference would also be appreciated!

Comment: Please see also my [answer here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43467/proving-that-the-fourier-coefficients-for-a-pretty-smooth-function-are-pretty-sma/43509#43509). Eric's excellent answer is of course sufficient but the answer to which I linked is for a similar question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For convenience, lets work on the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$.  Riemann Lesbegue just says that the Fourier coefficients of $f$ go to zero for an integrable function.  If $f$ is in $C^1(\mathbb{T})$ then we have that $\hat{f'}(n)=in\hat{f}(n)$.  (Here $\mathbb{T}$ refers to $[-\pi,\pi]$ with the endpoints identified.)  Since $f'$ is continuous it will be integrable, so Riemann Lesbegue implies the coefficients are $o(1)$.  Consequently the coefficients of $f$ are $o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$, and hence $$\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\sin(nx)dx=o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right).$$

For a function $f\in C^k(\mathbb{T})$ we get

$$\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\sin(nx)dx=o\left(\frac{1}{n^k}\right).$$

**What if $f\in C^1[-\pi,\pi]$, but $f(-\pi)\neq f(\pi)$?**

Since the coefficients of the [Sawtooth Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sawtooth_wave) have order $\frac{1}{n}$, we will not have a result as strong as before.  (The sawtooth function is $C^{\infty}[-\pi,\pi]$).

We can prove that if $f\in C^1[-\pi,\pi]$, but $f(-\pi)\neq f(\pi)$, then the fourier coefficients will be of order $\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: Hi Eric.  I was just double-checking this.  If you assume $f \in C^1[-\pi,\pi]$ but not necessarily periodic, it seems the non-vanishing boundary term gives you $O(1/n)$ rather than $o(1/n)$.

Comment: @John: Yeah, and for the $C^k$ part you also need that the periodic continuation of $f$ is $C^k$.

Comment: @Hendrik, @ John:  Sorry I forgot to add in that detail!  Thanks Hendrik for the correction, I edited the post to reflect that.

Comment: A remark, Theorem 4.1 in Katznelson's book tells us that R-L can not be improved http://tailieuhoctap.files.wordpress.com/2007/01/katznelson-y-an-introduction-to-harmonic-analysis-cup-2004299s_mcf_.pdf